# Force ad placement in Google AdSense plugin

Tags: wordpress, ads, adsense

Google AdSense plugin for WordPress (previously known as the Google Publisher Plugin) is showing me the placement for the "**after the last paragraph**" option inside the **last comment** on my blog.

Is there any way to tell the plugin where is the correct last paragraph `<p>` on the blog content?

I've tried [Manually insert placement code for the AdSense Plugin for WordPress](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6051417), but the plugin is not showing me the placement marker in the location where I added the code.

I know how to insert AdSense code manually, but I want to use the plugin in order to automatically add ad blocks with the same structure on every post.

Comment: Usually filtering `the_content` or calling the appropriate plugin function inside a template file should work it out. You can also check if those all serving with the Google Publisher Toolbar (Chrome extension).